# Weak Duals of Outerplanar Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

As part of my course, I have been given an assignment that goes as follows:

"The weak dual of a plane graph $G$ is the graph obtained from the dual $G^*$  by deleting the vertex for the unbounded region of $G$. Prove that the weak dual of an outerplane graph is a forest."

While I have tried this on multiple outerplanar graphs and it holds true, I am unable to come up with a rigorous proof for the same. Any ideas on how I could proceed? I did try looking it up online but found no free/openly available source that contained the proof (although many sources mentioned it was a well known fact).

Comment: To prove the weak dual is a forest, all you need to do is show it has no cycles. Try think what would have to happen in the original graph for there to be a cycle in the weak dual (you get a vertex surrounded by faces other than the unbounded one).